# Cognito logout does not work as documented

Tags: amazon-web-services, adfs, amazon-cognito

I have a Cognito user pool configured with a SAML identity provider (ADFS) and I'm able to sign it as a federated user (AD) but sign out does not work.

Following the [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/logout-endpoint.html), I make a GET request to 
https://my-domain.auth.us-west-2.amazoncognito.com/logout?client_id=63...ng&logout_uri=http:%2F%2Fyahoo.com (using some public logout uri), from my client (an AngularJS 1.x app), and I get back a 302 with a **Location** header like

```
https://my-domain.auth.us-west-2.amazoncognito.com/login?client_id=63...ng&logout_uri=http:%2F%2Fyahoo.com
```

(In fact there I see 2 requests like the above).

When I log back in (thru ADFS) it does not prompt for my AD credentials, i.e. seems that I'm not logged out.

My user pool is configured as described [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/cognito-user-pools-managing-saml-idp-console.html) (see step 7), where the **Enable IdP sign out flow** is checked, which is supposed to log the user out from ADFS as well.

Any suggestions?
Thanks.

```
General
-------
Request URL: https://my-domain.auth.us-west-2.amazoncognito.com/logout?client_id=63...ng&logout_uri=http:%2F%2Fyahoo.com  
Request Method: GET  
Status Code: 302  
Remote Address: 54.69.30.36:443  
Referrer Policy: no-referrer-when-downgrade  

Response Headers
----------------
cache-control: private  
content-length: 0  
date: Fri, 20 Apr 2018 21:31:12 GMT  
expires: Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 UTC  
location: https://my-domain.auth.us-west-2.amazoncognito.com/login?client_id=63...ng&logout_uri=http:%2F%2Fyahoo.com  
server: Server  
set-cookie: XSRF-TOKEN=...; Path=/; Secure; HttpOnly  
set-cookie: XSRF-TOKEN=""; Expires=Thu, 01-Jan-1970 00:00:10 GMT; Path=/; Secure; HttpOnly  
status: 302  
strict-transport-security: max-age=31536000 ; includeSubDomains  
x-content-type-options: nosniff  
x-frame-options: DENY  
x-xss-protection: 1; mode=block  

Request Headers
---------------
:authority: my-domain.auth.us-west-2.amazoncognito.com  
:method: GET  
:path: /logout?client_id=63...ng&logout_uri=http:%2F%2Fyahoo.com  
:scheme: https
accept: application/json, text/plain, */*  
accept-encoding: gzip, deflate, br  
accept-language: en-US,en;q=0.9  
authorization: Bearer eyJra...  
cache-control: no-cache  
origin: https://localhost:8443  
pragma: no-cache  
referer: https://localhost:8443/logout  
user-agent: Mozilla/5.0...
```

Comment: I am also facing the same problem. Did you solve it? Any inputs will help me.

Comment: Any resolution?

Comment: when you call logout endpoint, It does not invalidate existing tokens. https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-js/issues/3435

Answer (score 22):

This redirect happens whenever `logout_uri` parameter doesn't match exactly what's listed among **Sign out URL(s)** in AWS Cognito User Pools **App client settings** configuration.

Cognito allows logout with either `logout_uri` or with the same arguments as login (i.e. `redirect_uri` and `response_type`) to log out and take the user back to the login screen. It seems that whenever `logout_uri` is invalid, it assume the re-login flow, does this redirect, and then reports an error about missing login arguments.

As for SAML, I don't know, but guessing that it doesn't work because there was actually an error, just not properly reported.

Comment: This is exactly what I have experienced with ASP.NET Core with the Authentication Middleware. I was getting a correlation error because Cognito wasn't going back to my app to be redirected.

Comment: Yes, using Cognito behaves in a really horrible and counter-intuitive way. When there is a missing, invalid or not allowed URL `logout_uri` in the request it doesn't tell you. It implicitly tries to re-log you instead!

Comment: I had a similiar issue. Based on the user's role, we have different code path for a complete logout process i.e. multiple possible logout_uri. One of them was not configured in Cognito and it resulted in redirecting the user to the Cognito login screen with error "Required String parameter 'redirect_uri' is not present". (a very misleading error). As soon as I configured the missing logout_uri, the issue went away.

Comment: Ah. `logout_url` may not vary by even one character, not even a trailing `/`.

Answer (score 5):

The `/logout endpoint` signs the user out.**It only supports HTTPS GET**. It is working

Sample Requests  -  Logout and Redirect Back to Client

It clears out the existing session and redirects back to the client. Both parameters are required.

```
GET https://<YOUR DOMAIN NAME>/logout?
client_id=xxxxxxxxxxxx&
logout_uri=com.myclientapp://myclient/logout
```

Also make sure that **Logout URL is same as SIGNOUT URL in AWS Cognito APP** too.

for more information, refer [AWS LOGOUT Endpoint](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/logout-endpoint.html)

Answer (score 5):

From documentation here

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/logout-endpoint.html

If you want

[image]

And your login url is like

```
"https://xxxx.auth.eu-west-1.amazoncognito.com/login?client_id=1234&response_type=token&scope=aws.cognito.signin.user.admin+email+openid+phone+profile&redirect_uri=http://localhost:3000/"
```

Then your logout url is like

```
"https://xxxx.auth.eu-west-1.amazoncognito.com/logout?client_id=1234&logout_uri=http://localhost:3000/";
```

Note the difference

- login > login?  and  redirect_uri
- logout > logout?  and  logout_uri

Those redirect / logout uri must match what you have configured inside Cognito.

[image]

If you don't do it right, you may get strange errors like

```
error=unauthorized_client
```

or

```
Required String parameter 'response_type' is not present
```

and who knows what else. :o)

Answer (score 2):

My solution below is based on -
https://github.com/nextauthjs/next-auth/discussions/3938#discussioncomment-2165155

I am able to solve the issue with few changes-

in signout button upon clicking i will call handleSignOut

```
function handleSignOut() {
   const clientId = 'paste your AWS COGNITO CLIENT ID';
   const domain = 'paste your AWS COGNITO DOMAIN';
   window.location.href = `${domain}/logout?client_id=${clientId}&logout_uri=http://localhost:3000/logout`
}
```

In Aws cognito-> app integration -> app client settings -> signout url

keep the following url-
http://localhost:3000/logout

in pages create a seperate page called logout and keep following code-

```
import { useEffect } from "react"
import { signOut } from 'next-auth/react'

export default function SignoutPage() {

  useEffect(() => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      signOut({ callbackUrl: window.location.origin });
    }, 1000);
  }, []);
  
  return (
    <>
      <div className="loader">
        Loading..
      </div>
      <style jsx>{`
        .loader{
          position: fixed;
          top: 50%;
          left: 50%;
          transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
          transform: -webkit-translate(-50%, -50%);
          transform: -moz-translate(-50%, -50%);
          transform: -ms-translate(-50%, -50%);
        }
      `}</style>
    </>
  )
}
```

click signout it will log you out

Answer (score 1):

Finally I was able to fix this issue. I found the actual cause of the issue from the event viewer of my windows server 2012 R2. It says the following details about the failed sign out flow.

The SAML Single Logout request does not correspond to the logged-in session participant.
Requestor: urn:amazon:cognito:sp:userpoolid
Request name identifier: Format: urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:nameid-format:persistent, NameQualifier:  SPNameQualifier: , SPProvidedId:
Logged-in session participants:
Count: 1, [Issuer: urn:amazon:cognito:sp:userpoolid, NameID: (Format: , NameQualifier:  SPNameQualifier: , SPProvidedId: )]

User Action
Verify that the claim provider trust or the relying party trust configuration is up to date. If the name identifier in the request is different from the name identifier in the session only by NameQualifier or SPNameQualifier, check and correct the name identifier policy issuance rule using the AD FS 2.0 Management snap-in.

The Error clearly says that the name identifier in the request is different from the name identifier in the session only by NameQualifier. I have corrected this error in the claim issuance tab of relying party trusts by adding the rule as below. The below rule replace the user@myadfsdomain to simply user when issuing the claim.

```
c:[Type == "http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/claims/windowsaccountname"]
 => issue(Type = "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/nameidentifier", Issuer = c.Issuer, OriginalIssuer = c.OriginalIssuer, Value = RegExReplace(c.Value, "(?i)^myadfsdomain*\\", ""), ValueType = c.ValueType, Properties["http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claimproperties/format"] = "urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:nameid-format:persistent");
```

Besides this i have forgot to check in the enable signout flow in the cognito configuration which caused the problem. Logout started working seamlessly for me.

Comment: How did you enable signout flow?

Comment: Inside the cognito identity provider section, there will be a small checkbox to enable signout flow. By default it is not checked. check it to enable signout flow.

Comment: Oh okay, saw it. I am using OIDC that's why I can't find it. In my case looks like it is a known limitation of Cognito - https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=882529

Answer (score 0):

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/logout", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public void logout(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
    LOGGER.info("Logout controller");
    try {
        Cookie awsCookie = new Cookie("AWSELBAuthSessionCookie-0", "deleted");
        awsCookie.setMaxAge(-1);
        awsCookie.setPath("/");
        response.addCookie(awsCookie);
        Properties appProperties = new Properties();
        applicationPropertyConfigurer.loadProperties(appProperties);
        response.sendRedirect(appProperties.getProperty("logout.url"));
        response.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate, max-age=0");
        response.setHeader("Pragma", "no-cache");
        response.setDateHeader("Expires", -1);
        request.getSession().invalidate();

    } catch (IOException e) {
        LOGGER.error("Exception in redirecting to logout.url URL", e);
    }

}
```

//https:/domain_name.auth.us-west-x.amazoncognito.com/logout?response_type=code&client_id=&redirect_uri=redirect_uri_should_be_present_in_cognito_user_pool_Callback URL&state=STATE&scope=openid

Comment: It is mentioned in document that Cognito endpoint clears session. what session it clears? why we need to manually delete as above code? what is the difference?